# How can I temporarily protect party walls exposed to elements?

Tags: walls, structural

We're in old townhomes/rowhouses made with balloon construction so the side structures butt up against each other so with their walls demoed out you can seem my insulation and whatnot.

Due to the vacant gutted home next door the interior backside of my walls/insulation are exposed to the elements. Because I’m able to get into the property is there a simple, cost-effective solution that I can use to better protect my property from possible damage from the elements while waiting for the owner of the property to begin construction at some point?

For example could I run house wrap or the black tar roofing paper along the walls top to bottom as a layer of protection or would something like this just promote mold growth?

If it's helpful, the home's located in northern NJ and is balloon construction (so that side is one big party wall).

Any info's appreciated!

Comment: Well they should be responsible for covering the exposed wall with a tarp or something

Comment: "should be" is right. They "should have" also completely boarded up their place and the city's not the most helpful but that's beyond the point at the moment haha

Comment: What's "simple" and "cost-effective" largely depends on your skills, tools, and store inventory. Literally _anything_ that's waterproof will do. I'm not sure what you're hoping we'll tell you. Just slap up some tarps.

Comment: Welcome, and please take the [tour].

Comment: I guess because I'm trying to patch something together to make a bad situation better and limit any potential damage down the road, I don't want to make it worse or potentially cause damage myself. Thanks, I hadn't actually thought of just getting tarps. I defaulted to house wrap or roofing felt. Would using tarps encourage mold growth at all or would that be less of a concern since everything behind them should be dry and the tarps aren't sealing off the area from air movement? Thanks again.

Comment: "Balloon framing" usually refers to studs that start at the top of the foundation walls and run all the way to the roof. Is this what you're referring to? Not sure how that impacts temporary weather protection either way, though...

Comment: That's exactly it and It honestly doesn't have anything to do with this but I mentioned it because in the past people have asked for random details so I just overshare haha